# ¿Cómo actualizar sólo una parte de una página de asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Tengo un DropDownList con el que lleno un Listbox, pero el dropdownlist tiene activado el AutoPostBack=true, para poder utilizar el evento de SelectedIndexChanged, el problema es que también tengo un Grid, y cuando cambio el index del DropDownList, se refresca toda la página, y no quiero que pase eso, porque el grid también se refresca, hay alguna manera de sólo se recargue el ListBox cuando cambie de Index en el DropDownList, éste es mi código que he intentado:

```
     <div class="form-control">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                            </asp:ScriptManager>
                            <br />
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSetSession" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>

                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsuarios" runat="server"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsuarios_SelectedIndexChanged"
                            AutoPostBack="true">
                        </asp:DropDownList>

                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCorreoAdd" runat="server" placeholder="Añadir correo a lista"></asp:TextBox>

                         <asp:Label ID="lblIngrese" runat="server" CssClass="success" Text="Ingrese nombre, sólo si desea crear una nueva lista"></asp:Label>

                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtNombreLista" runat="server" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre" Width="123px" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnInserta" runat="server" Text="Insertar en la lista" CssClass="btn-circle blue" OnClick="btnInserta_Click" />

                        <br />

                                          </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlUsuarios"
                                        EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        <br />
                    </div>
```

ASP.NET C#

```
 protected void ddlUsuarios_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ListCorreos.Items.Clear();
                NombreLista = ddlUsuarios.SelectedItem.Text;
                List(NombreLista);
                for (int i = 0; i < lstNotificar1.Count; i++)
                {
                    ListCorreos.Items.Add(lstNotificar1.ElementAt(i));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿has intentado usar AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que lo que tienes que tener dentro del `UpdatePanel` son los elementos que se van a actualizar cuando se realice el postback asíncrono.

Es decir, cuando llamas al evento `SelectedIndexChanged` actualizas el contenido del control `ListCorreos`, es por tanto éste el control que debería estar dentro del `UpdatePanel`.

Algo así:

```
<div class="form-control">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsuarios" runat="server"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsuarios_SelectedIndexChanged"
        AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCorreoAdd" runat="server" placeholder="Añadir correo a lista"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Label ID="lblIngrese" runat="server" CssClass="success" Text="Ingrese nombre, sólo si desea crear una nueva lista"></asp:Label>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNombreLista" runat="server" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre" Width="123px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnInserta" runat="server" Text="Insertar en la lista" CssClass="btn-circle blue" OnClick="btnInserta_Click" />

    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upSetSession" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListBox ID="ListCorreos" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlUsuarios"
                EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <br />
</div>
```